# How do I use "or" when comparing two strings from input()

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

```
action = input("\nOption: ")
if action.lower() == "1" or "door":
    if kitchen_key == 0:
        typewriter("You try to wrestle the door open, you swear you could remove the door from it's hinges... ... ... ... But you fail, you dejectedly return to the kitchen.")
        time.sleep(1)
        kitchen_choices()
    elif kitchen_key == 1:
        typewriter("With your newfound key you swiftly jam the key into the hole and twist. CLUNK! The sound of being one step closer to freedom! You pull the door open and continue on your way!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("proceeding to next room")
if action.lower() == "2" or "stove":
    stove()
```

Above I'm asking the user for input and to give outcomes depending on what they typed. However the above only runs the first option so: "You try to wrestle the door open, you swear you could remove the door from it's hinges" is my outcome, even if I press 2. However if I use "and" in place of "or" it works but will not take in strings like "door" or "stove" and only 1 or 2. Can someone explain how this error is coming about and what I could do to fix it.

This is for a beginner project but none of my team can figure out why this is the case.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `or` is a boolean operator. Your line

```
if action.lower() == "1" or "door":
```

is equivalent to

```
if (action.lower() == "1") or "door":
```

since a non-empty string always returns true. The boolean statement is evaluated to:

```
if (action.lower() == "1") or True:
```

and `or`ing with True always return the conditions.
So the code evaluates to

```
if action.lower() == "1":
```

To fix it all you need to do is put the `or` between two boolean statement

```
if action.lower() == "1" or action.lower() == "door":
```

and similiarly

```
if action.lower() == "2" or action.lower() == "stove":
```

or you do as SorousH Bakhiatry suggested and do

```
if action.lower() in ("1", "door"):
```

But that's less readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`and` and `or` acts differently from English language.  Here is a link if you wanna learn more : [from docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Change your condition to :

```
if action.lower() in ("1", "door"):
```

Comment: Actually their code is almost correct, you can definitely use `or` there, the only difference is they need to use `or` between the two boolean conditions.

Comment: @kinshukdua yes it's true syntactically but the result is not what he is looking for. As `"door"` always evaluated to True.

Comment: Yes and you should explain *why* the code was not working and how to use `or` correctly with booleans instead of posting a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

my solution was having a variable check on the other side of the or...

```
if action.lower() == "1" or action.lower() == "stairs":
```

as well as changing the second if to an elif...

```
elif action.lower() == "2" or action.lower() == "stove": 
    stove()
```

Thank you for your responses and answers, there's things you have linked I need to research.
Thanks!